# How to find modified file and user name on current date in google drive in python by google drive api?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I want to see a dataframe that can show file name, folder name , last modified date i.e today and user modified.

As I have lots of folders and I have to look in all folders to look which file is modified so trying to look in `colab` or by `google_picker_api` `https://developers.google.com/picker/docs` or

by `google_drive_api` or by `google_activity_api`  [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2)

For example:

```
for file in drive_folder:
  if file_modified ==current_Date in file.data:
   print(file, user_modifed,date_modifed)
```

desire_output:

```
  file_name   folder last_date_modified user_modified
0 spreadsheet abc     20220307           'david'
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to gather the list of files, you would need to use the Drive API V3.

I was able to find an example Python  code and documentation to utilize query.

One of the examples can allow you to find "[Files modified after a given date](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#python)"

The parameters or fields needed to get the folder, last modified, user and modified would be:

1. parent: It would give you the ID of the parent folder.
2. lastModifyingUser: It would give you the information of the user that made the last modification
3. displayName: For the user that modifies it

You can actually test the API for Drive [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) or [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

For files.list:

Over the "fields" parameter just add "*" and it would give you all the fields with data about the files of your organization.

For files.get:

You can add the same as above and the ID of any particular file you have.

Sample code edit based on the [quickstart for Python.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)

```js
# Call the Drive v3 API
results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=10,
    fields="parent, files(id, name)",
    q="modifiedTime > '2012-06-04T12:00:00-08:00'").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])
if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

Comment: I can't see last modified user parameters in the link?

Comment: Using the "q" parameters, let me edit the answer by adding the example code based on the [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)